# How to fold text in a JSON file?

Tags: gvim, folding

I have a large JSON file. It is not easy to work on all file at a time.
I want to fold some content so that I can work on a section of JSON file.

E.g.:

```
{
  obj: {+}, // folded section
  obj:{
        // unfolded section
     }
}
```

Is it possible to fold JSON structure in Vim?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. A minimal setup would be:

```
:set filetype=json
:syntax on
:set foldmethod=syntax
```

Comment: what keystroke needed to fold and unfold a section?

Comment: `:h fold-commands` - `zo` - open and `zc` - close

Comment: `za` - toggle fold

Comment: FWIW: This isn't enabling folding for me.  "E490: No fold found".

Comment: @spazm: So you can probably ask a new question here, describe what OS you're using, what exact editor, what version, all the steps you're doing, all the info that could be helpful.

Comment: Amazing. This even works with files that are only partially JSON.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using nvim and [nvim-treesitter](https://github.com/nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter#supported-languages). You can also use treesitter to fold JSON files.

Config for nvim-treesitter:

```
require("nvim-treesitter.configs").setup {
  ensure_installed = { "python", "cpp", "lua", "vim", "json" },
  ignore_install = {}, -- List of parsers to ignore installing
  highlight = {
    enable = true, -- false will disable the whole extension
    disable = { 'help' }, -- list of language that will be disabled
  },
}
```

Make sure that json parser for treesitter is installed.

Then create `after/ftplugin/json.vim` with following config:

```
set foldmethod=expr
set foldexpr=nvim_treesitter#foldexpr()
```

Open a valid json file, you should be able to see the files are folded properly.

Ref:

https://github.com/nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter/issues/1337#issuecomment-864205387